# IE 8 always refreshes

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js v1.2.0, I tested our web app in IE 8 and when it goes to another page it just reloads infinitely. Everything works well in Chrome and Firefox though.

Do you have any thoughts why is this happening? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to HTML 5 working in IE 8. Our workaround for this was to utilize a browser checker in javascript to check what browser is being used by the web app.  If the browser is IE 8 then we'll turn off HTML5 mode `html5mode(false)`, Else we'll set `html5mode` method to true.